# Closed form of a specific recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have the following equation which I am trying to find the closed form for: 
$$ x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}-\frac{x_{n}}{2}$$

So far rearranging and substituting has yielded the following equations:

$$2x_{n+1}+ x_{n-1} = 1$$

$$2x_{n+1} =  x_{n}+ x_{n-1}$$
$$2x_{n+1} = 1- x_{n}$$
$$ 6x_{n+1} - x_{n}-2x_{n-1} =1$$
$$4x_{n+1} - x_{n-1}=1$$
I've just been trying to solve a jumble of these equations which hasn't yielded much so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You've mixed up $n$ and $n-1$. A good way to approach these problems is to make a guess for what $x_n$ is and then solve for the unknowns. Try $x_n=an^2+bn+c$, for example.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Note what you have is a relatively simple [linear difference equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_difference_equation).

Comment: @ElliotG which equation have i mixed them in ?

Comment: Please see my previous post here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2400524/solving-simple-linear-recurrences-with-generating-functions/2402627#2402627. It has a more general solution to the problem than what has been given to you so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y_n=x_n-\frac 1  3$ then $y_{n+1}=-\frac {y_n} 2$ and you can iterate this easily.

[If $x_n$ converges the limit has to be $\frac  1 3$ from the given recurrence relation. This suggests that you look at $x_n-\frac  1 3$].

Comment: $\frac 1 3$ is a fixed point of this recurrence relation. In general, is making a transformation $y_n = x_n - \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a fixed point (if possible), a good strategy to solve these kinds of problems?

Comment: Well, solving the recurrence relation explicitly is not even possible in most cases, but in simple cases like this it is certainly a good idea to write the recurrence relation in terms of $x_n-\alpha$.  @EhWha

Comment: Thanks for your help. That was super clear

Answer (score 2):

Let $ n $ be a positive integer, wa have that : \begin{aligned} \left(\forall k<n\right),\ x_{n-k}&=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x_{n-k-1}}{2}\\ \iff \left(\forall k<n\right),\ \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}x_{n-k}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}+\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}x_{n-k-1}\\ \iff \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}x_{n-k}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k+1}x_{n-k-1}\right)}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}}\\ \iff x_{n}-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}x_{0}&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}}{1-\frac{1}{2}} \end{aligned}

And thus : $$ \left(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ x_{n}=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n}x_{0}+1-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n} $$